# How can you lock start the screen-saver in OS X with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, screensaver

I want to be able to lock the screen quickly, and and the hot-corner thing is slow and tricky.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Using Keychain Access's Lock Screen menubar isn't fast enough for you?

Activate it here:

[image: keychain preference]

Then lock.

[image: keychain menubar]

Comment: How do you get to that first Preferences window?

Comment: I originally shy'ed away from this, since I wanted a keyboard-only approach, in the hopes that it would be faster than a mouse approach, but given the delay in my automator script actually running, this is a viable alternative.

Comment: Oh, and the first preferences window is in KeychainAccess.app's Preferences.

Answer (score 2):

What version of OS X are you using?  In 10.5, I used [LockTight](http://www.gkoya.com/2006/11/23/locktight-for-mac-os-x-intel/), but it didn't work very well for me in 10.6, so now I am using an [automator script](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20090831093941225).

The automator script works, but there is a delay between when I hit the key-combination, and when it locks up, especially if the currently activated application is busy (and I usually like to start some big task, like a build, right before I walk aay from my desk).

Answer (score 2):

Control-shift-eject (or control-shift-power) puts displays to sleep and option-command-eject (or option-command-power) puts a Mac to sleep. Both lock the Mac if this option is selected:

[image]

Another way to lock a Mac is to log out to the fast user switching screen. You can assign a keyboard shortcut for it with Alfred:

[image]

Or just assign a shortcut to `/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend`.

Comment: Thanks. It has been 3.5 years since I've used a Mac, so I won't be able to test this, but it looks useful.

Answer (score 1):

Both shift-control-eject and option-command-eject (or power if you don't have an eject key) will sleep the display. You can require a password to wake from sleep in the Security & Privacy system preferences.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the new MacBook Pro, use a program like [Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) to map from a key you choose to "Eject", so that the good old CTRL-SHIFT-EJECT works.

This method works also with external / Windows keyboards (no Power key)

For example:

[image]